# RTF Viewer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I need to know how to view a .RTF file content in a webpage . In Winform it's have a RichTextBox to display the contents But How to achieve this in Webforms . Any One Know this Issue .

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery fits your development model, there are several RTF jQuery modules.  CKEditor being one we use.

[CKEditor RTF Control](http://ckeditor.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Also you could try [RTE](http://rte.codeplex.com/) found on codeplex

A demo of it in action can be found [here](http://rteditor.members.winisp.net/)