# Rich Text Viewer In ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RTF Viewer in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785392/rtf-viewer-in-asp-net)

I want to view a RTF format file in asp.net and don't want to edit . Just a simple viewer like crystal report do . Any suggestion ...

Comment: a few options provided on nearly similar question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785392/rtf-viewer-in-asp-net

Comment: search "rtf to html asp.net" and find the one you like.